# How do I specify a requirement for a minimum version of openssl in RPM spec file?

Tags: rpm, openssl, version

The rpm spec file for my package looks like this:

```
Requires:mysql-server >= 5.5.30, java >= 1.6, p7zip, openssl >= 1.0.2g
```

I have an RHEL system where the OpenSSL version is this:

```
[ag@rhel1]# openssl 
OpenSSL> version 
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
[ag@rhel1]# rpm -q --whatprovides openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64
```

When I try to test the install of my RPM package, it is supposed to fail because my package requires a minimum of `1.0.2g` whereas `1.0.1e` is installed. However, the installation succeeds without any problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: Already asked (and answered) at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36762936/3489429. Please ask only on one site.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the comparison should work...

How are you installing the rpm? E.g. do you use `yum localinstall` or `rpm`?

Can you check if the rpm you built contains the correct requirements?
(Using `rpm -qip --requires YourPackage.rpm`)

You can check how rpm does version comparison with the `rpmdevtools`:

```
# yum -y install rpmdevtools
# rpmdev-vercmp openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64 openssl-1.0.2g
openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64 < openssl-1.0.2g
```

PS. The [--whatprovides](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html) only shows you which package on you system provides the `openssl` capability. If you want to know what exactly the installed package provides, you have to run `rpm -q --provides openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64`